# Pandas selecting evry time the first row with index >= X and then the next row with index >= 2X

Tags: pandas, dataframe, select, row

I have solved a mathematical equation and generated a frame with time as an index  with time values t = np.linspace(0, 15, 100), so in 15 hours, 100 timepoints. Now i want to select evry 2 hours the value of that frame. In my case the value at 2.12 and then at 4.09 and later 6.06 and so on. Is there an option to choose for example the first row for index = time greater or equal than 2 which is 2.12 and then the next row is the first value with time >= 4 which is 4.09 and so on?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at `searchsorted`:

```
t[np.searchsorted(t,np.arange(0,15,2)]
```

Out:

```
array([ 0.        ,  2.12121212,  4.09090909,  6.06060606,  8.03030303,
       10.        , 12.12121212, 14.09090909])
```